# Gnome shows ethernet connected when cable is unplugged

Tags: debian, gnome3, ethernet, connectivity

I'm trying to connect to the internet on my Debian 12 laptop using my phone connection through an USB-C cable.

When the cable is connected and the connection sharing is activated on the phone, the Ethernet symbol shows up on the top bar of the desktop (Gnome 43.6). However, I cannot connect to any website from the laptop, although it's accessible from my phone.

I tried to shut down and boot again with the cable unplugged, and now the Ethernet symbol shows up directly when booting. I still cannot connect when plugging the cable in again. I also can't connect through my phone's Wifi hotspot with the cable unplugged.

Both Ethernet and Wifi have been regularly working between these two devices until now. I suspect Debian is stuck on some kind of old connection it cannot get rid of. What should I do?

Comment: Please show the output of commands `nmcli d` and `ip link show` (copy & paste them into your original question, if possible) for starters. If the `nmcli d` shows any interface in a `connected` state with the phone unplugged, please also run `/sbin/ethtool -i <device name>`, replacing `<device name>` with the actual name of the device in the `DEVICE` column of `nmcli d`.

Comment: Thank to your suggestion (I didn't know about `nmcli`), I could resolve my problem. The command showed me two lines related to my VPN (kill switch and leak protection), which gave me the idea. I then simply started my VPN client, through which I could connect to the internet. When I shut down the VPN, the two related lines disappeared from `nmcli d` result and the problem was gone. I think the cause is that my VPN doesn't support unexpected shutdowns due to low battery.

Comment: You should write an actual answer to your question (instead of just a comment), showing the VPN-related lines in the `nmcli d` output. That way this question would better help others with a similar problem.You might want to mention the name of your VPN client, but feel free to redact out any personally identifiable information. Since `nmcli d` output is just text, it is easily copy/pasteable, and also works for people who need technological assistance with various sight issues.